# Qual a melhor estratégia de validação antes de persistir os dados?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, validação, ado.net

Eu estou acostumado com .NET usando C# e EntityFramework.

E lá no Entity temos as `dataanotations`. Quando crio a entidade no C#, por exemplo de pessoa, basta colocar as `datanotaations` e o Entity valida pra mim:

```
public partial class Tab_Parente
{
  [Key]
  public int Cpf { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Nome da Pessoa")]
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Nome Aluno deve ser informado.")]
  publicint Nome{ get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "CPF")]
  [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "O CPF deve ter no máximo 15 caracteres.")]
  public string Cpf { get; set; }
}
```

Porém comecei em um projeto que exige ADO. Aí me veio a pergunta: Qual a melhor maneira de fazer a validação dos dados antes de persistir com o ADO?

Será que terei que criar um método de validação para cada campo e chamar todos eles antes de enviar um comando de `update` ou `insert` para o banco?

Tipo ver se o ID já existe com um `select`. Ver se o CPF informado tem mais de 15 caracteres, etc., tudo na mão?

**--------------------EDIÇÃO---------------------**
***Encontrei minha resposta:***

Bom ao contrario do que eu pensava e afirmei anteriormente os DataAnnotations podem sim ser utilizados em aplicações WindowsForms.

Muita gente não sabe mas Data Annotations não são exclusivos do MVC, nem muito menos restrito ao Entity Framework. Seguindo um tutorial do Macoratti sobre o uso do: Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, contexto, resultadoValidacao , true) Pude construir uma classe getValidationErros(object obj), que nos retorna uma lista de erros de uma entidade. Em meu projeto Windows Forms e utilizando ADO puro.

Vejam como ficou:

Entidade

```
public class HoldingGrupoEnt : GeralEntidade, IHoldingGrupoEnt
{
    [Display(Name = "Código Grupo", Description = "Código do grupo.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "000001 - Código Grupo não pode ficar vazio em Holding Grupo.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "000002 - Somente números (de 0 a 9) são permitidos para Código Grupo em Holding Grupo.")]
    public string CodigoGrupo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome Fantasia", Description = "Nome completo.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome fantasia é obrigatório.")]
    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

    public IHoldingGrupoStatusRegistroEnt HoldingGrupoStatusRegistroEnt { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DataCadastro { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Validacao

```
public static class Validacao
{
    public static IEnumerable<ValidationResult> getValidationErros(object obj)
    {
        var resultadoValidacao = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var contexto = new ValidationContext(obj, null, null);
        Validator.TryValidateObject(obj, contexto, resultadoValidacao, true);
        return resultadoValidacao;
    }
}
```

Método no Contexto da Entidade (onde estão os metodos Update, insert, etc)

```
public override bool ValidaRegistro()
{
    DadosValidados = false;

    if (DadosRecebidos)
    {
        var erros = Validacao.getValidationErros(ObjetoEnt);
        foreach (var error in erros)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((error.ErrorMessage));
        }
    }
    //return DadosValidados = (erros.ToString() = 0) ;
    return DadosValidados = true;
}
```

Além disso ainda não sei bem como mas já me disseram que o Fluent Validation também pode ser usado fora do mundinho do MVC.

Comment: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation usaria esse

Comment: Opa! Então ainda há esperança, rsrs. Vou dar uma olhada @Marconcilio

Answer (score 7):

Basicamente é isto. Claro que não precisa ser necessariamente um método para cada validação, pode ser um método que faça todos. Aí é uma questão de organização do projeto. Cada projeto pode exigir uma solução diferente.

Ou pode criar um *framework* semelhante ao EF para automatizar isto e ter comportamento parecido onde pode só anotar e usar. As anotações até existem, mas não tem nada que execute as ações necessárias quando encontram essas anotações. Certamente existem alguns prontos que podem já fazer uma tarefa assim.

Comment: Hummm pouxa vida. Então terei um belo trabalho pela frente, rsrs. Melhor começar logo. Obrigado pela resposta.